# How to add internal article links in Joomla 3 articles edit page (outside the WYSIWYG editor)?

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla3.0

In Joomla articles edit page, there are 3 custom links- Link A, Link B and Link C. Is there a way to easily add internal article links to these 3 custom links? Are there similar extensions that help achieve this feature? Currently the links must be manually entered and I am looking at having the links outside the WYSIWYG editor.

Comment: If you limit it to menu links you could use a plugin to replace the field types which are currently url with the field that gives a list of articles that is used when creating an article menu link.

Comment: You mean creating a custom plugin for it?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what form modification in jform is designed for

Answer (score 0):

> Are there similar extensions that help achieve this feature?

This is exactly what I would use. Although your description is short I azume you want to enter similar articles or use those links to group articles. No matter what article you open you always see links to all of them. It is like one tutorial in few parts.

I can suggest to use [Cobalt CCK](http://www.mintjoomla.com/joomla-components/cobalt.html).

This is an alternative content manager. It has content field called *Records* and *Read Also*. Those fields allow you to connect unlimited number of other article. You can connect similar articles without selecting them manually like for example *Cars of the same year* or *other phones with camera* or *People who likes this also likes*.

In *read also* field you will be able to select related articles manually. It have double bond connection. It means that if in article A tou select article B, then you will see link to article B in article A and link to article A in article B.